# Not Reaching Controller - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

iam trying to insert data to database but button is not working it is not inserting the data but it redirect to laravel welcome page .

this is blade

```
 <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="{{ route('Countries.store') }}" method="post" autocomplete="off"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link @if (LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale() == 'ar') active @endif" id="homeIcon-tab"
                                data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#homeIcon" aria-controls="home" role="tab"
                                aria-selected="true">
                                <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-ae"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                {{ trans('Dashboard/General.Arabic') }}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link @if (LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale() == 'en') active @endif" id="profileIcon-tab"
                                data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#profileIcon" aria-controls="profile" role="tab"
                                aria-selected="false">
                                <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                {{ trans('Dashboard/General.English') }}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane @if (LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale() == 'ar') active @endif" id="homeIcon"
                            aria-labelledby="homeIcon-tab" role="tabpanel">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="mb-1">
                                    <label class="form-label"
                                        for="basicInput">{{ trans('Dashboard/Countries.CountryName') }}</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basicInput"
                                        placeholder="{{ trans('Dashboard/Countries.CountryName') }}" name="CountryNameAR">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane @if (LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale() == 'en') active @endif" id="profileIcon"
                            aria-labelledby="profileIcon-tab" role="tabpanel">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="mb-1">
                                    <label class="form-label"
                                        for="basicInput">{{ trans('Dashboard/Countries.CountryName') }}</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basicInput"
                                        placeholder="{{ trans('Dashboard/Countries.CountryName') }}" name="CountryNameEN">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cardMaster rounded border p-2 mb-1">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-sm-row flex-column">
                            <div class="row col-12">
                                <div class="card-information col-6">
                                    <div class="mb-1">
                                        <label class="form-label"
                                            for="first-name-column">{{ trans('Dashboard/Countries.CountryPhoneCode') }}</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="first-name-column" class="form-control"
                                            placeholder="{{ trans('Dashboard/Countries.CountryPhoneCode') }}"
                                            name="fname-column">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex flex-column col-6">
                                    <div class="mb-1">
                                        <label class="form-label"
                                            for="last-name-column">{{ trans('Dashboard/Countries.CountryNumCode') }}</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="last-name-column" class="form-control"
                                            placeholder="{{ trans('Dashboard/Countries.CountryNumCode') }}"
                                            name="lname-column">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cardMaster rounded border p-2 mb-1">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-sm-row flex-column">
                            <div class="row col-12">
                                <div class="mb-1">
                                    <label class="form-label"
                                        for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">{{ trans('Dashboard/General.Notes') }}</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"
                                        placeholder="{{ trans('Dashboard/General.Notes') }}"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cardMaster rounded border p-2 mb-1">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-sm-row flex-column">
                            <div class="row col-12">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                                    <div class="mb-1">
                                        <label class="form-label">
                                            {{ trans('Dashboard/Countries.CountryFlag') }}
                                        </label>

                                        <!-- upload and reset button -->
                                        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                                            <div>
                                                <label id="courser" for="account-upload"
                                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mb-75 me-75">{{ trans('Dashboard/General.Upload') }}
                                                </label>
                                                <input type="file" id="account-upload" name="account-upload" hidden
                                                    accept="image/*" />

                                                <button onclick="changeImage()" type="button" id="account-reset"
                                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary mb-75 waves-effect">{{ trans('Dashboard/General.Reset') }}
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--/ upload and reset button -->

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                                    <div class="mb-1">
                                        <a href="#" class="me-25">
                                            <img src="{{ asset('Dashboard/images/NoImage.png') }}"
                                                id="account-upload-img" class="uploadedAvatar rounded me-50"
                                                alt="No Image" height="150" width="150" />
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-sm-row flex-column">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column text-start text-lg-end">
                            <div class="d-flex order-sm-0 order-1 mt-1 mt-sm-0">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-1 waves-effect waves-float waves-light">
                                    {{ trans('Dashboard/General.Save') }}
                                </button>
                                <a type="button" href="{{ route('Countries.index') }}"
                                    class="btn btn-outline-secondary waves-effect">
                                    {{ trans('Dashboard/General.Back') }}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is the Repository

```
 public function store($request)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        try {
            $validated = $request->validated();
            $countries = new Country();
            $countries->CountryName = ['en' => $request->CountryNameEN, 'ar' => $request->CountryNameAR];
            $countries->CountryPhoneCode = $request->CountryPhoneCode;
            $countries->CountryNumCode = $request->CountryNumCode;
            $countries->CountryNotes = $request->CountryNotes;
            $countries->CreatedBy = Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id;
            $countries->CreatedAt = CommonHelper::getDateTime();
            $countries->CreatedDeviceName = $get_device = UserInfoHelper::get_device();
            $countries->Createdip = $get_ip = UserInfoHelper::get_ip();
            $countries->save();

            // Insert Image
            $this->verifyAndStoreImage($request, 'photo', $request->CountryNameEN, 'Countries', 'upload_image', $countries->CountryID, 'App\Models\Country');

            DB::commit();
            session()->flash('Add');
            return redirect()->route('Countries.index');

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
```

And interface

```
 public function store($request);
```

And Controller

```
protected $Countries;

public function __construct(CountryRepositoryInterface $Countries)
{
    $this->Countries = $Countries;
}

public function store(StoreCountry $request)
{
    return $this->Countries->store($request);
}
```

For request

```
class StoreCountry extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'CountryNameAR' => 'required',
            'CountryNameEN' => 'required',
            'CountryPhoneCode' => 'required',
            'CountryNumCode' => 'required',
            'account-upload' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:1024',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'CountryNameAR.required' => trans('Countries.CountryArabicName_error'),
            'CountryNameEN.required' => trans('Countries.CountryEnglishName_error'),
            'CountryPhoneCode.required' => trans('Countries.CountryPhoneCode_error'),
            'CountryNumCode.required' => trans('Countries.CountryNumCode_error'),
            'account-upload.image' => trans('Countries.Mustbeimage_error'),
            'account-upload.mimes' => trans('Countries.Imagemimes_error'),
            'account-upload.max' => trans('Countries.Imagemax_error'),
        ];
    }
}
```

I tried to change the form location but the issue still the controller dos not reachable when i click the submit button it redirect me to Laravel welcome page
Kind Regards

Comment: I don't see anything that would force it to the welcome page. I would suggest adding some logging along path the code should take. My favorite way to trace is to add `Log::info(__CLASS__.':'.__FUNCTION__);` at the beginning of every function, then check the laravel logs to see where it's going.

Comment: it give this 

local.ERROR: Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\CountryController]. {"exception":"[object] (UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): Invalid route action: [App\\Http\\Controllers\\Dashboard\\CountryController]. at C:\\Users\\rrr\\Desktop\\Laravel\\Laravel Projects\\Hospital\\TestProject\\HospitalManagementSystem\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteAction.php:92)

Comment: what is the content of your ```route.php```?

Comment: `Route::middleware(['auth:admin'])->group(function () {
           
            Route::resource('Countries', CountryController::class);
          
        }`

Comment: Can you do `php artisan route:list` and show us what it says for the store function?

Comment: GET|HEAD        Countries Countries.index › Dashboard\CountryController@ind…
POST            Countries Countries.store › Dashboard\CountryController@sto…
GET|HEAD        Countries/create Countries.create › Dashboard\CountryContro…
GET|HEAD        Countries/{Country} Countries.show › Dashboard\CountryContr…
  PUT|PATCH       Countries/{Country} Countries.update › Dashboard\CountryCon…
  DELETE          Countries/{Country} Countries.destroy › Dashboard\CountryCo…
  GET|HEAD        Countries/{Country}/edit Countries.edit › Dashboard\Country…

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the information there, for both the error and routes. it's almost unreadable in comments.

Comment: What is the full namespace of `CountryController`?

Comment: namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard;